# Number of subgroups and elements of the group $G=C_{12}\times C_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Imagine that we've got  a group $G=C_{12}\times C_2$ and I need to now how many **subgroups and elements** of order 6 has G got.

---

First of all, I've calculated the cardinal of $G$: $|G=C_{12}\times C_2|=|C_{12}||C_2|=12\cdot2=24$

Then, I've started with the subgroups: If I'm not wrong, $G$ is going to have only one subgroup of order &6& owing to the fact that $6$ is adivisor of $24$.

Then, for the elements, I know that if I take an element $(a,b)\in G,\space o[(a,b)]=[o(a),o(b)]\space $ where $\space o(a)|12\space , \space o(b)|2$. So the possible combinations are: $[6,1],[3,2]$ and $[6,2]$. And there are two chances for each one, so have we got in total $6$ elements of order 6?

Comment: [This might help.](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2xC12.html)

Comment: I think you’re wrong, because $C_6\times C_1$ and $C_3\times C_2$ are different subgroups of order $6$

Comment: So how can I do it? What is wrong?

Comment: There is a third subgroup of order $6$ generated by $(a^2,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are generators of the two direct factors.

Comment: So $G$ has got one cyclic subgroup of order $6$ and other non-cyclic subgroup of order$6$ which is $(a^2,b)$ ?

Comment: If $H \leq G$ with $|H|=6$, then $|G/H|=4$. We know there are two non-isomorphic groups of order $4$, namely $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ (one of which is cyclic and the other is not). So now you can determine the possibilities for $H$ in a systematic manner.

Comment: There are three subgroups of order 6 and they are all cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of an element $(a,b)$ in the product is $\rm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

We have $3$ cyclic subgroups of order $6$.  They're all cyclic because any abelian group of order $6$ is.

My reasoning is that $C_{12}$ has $\varphi(6)=2$ elements of order six.  But they both generate the same subgroup.  Pair that subgroup with $e$ or $C_2$, for two.

Meanwhile, $C_{12}$ has $\varphi(3)=2$ elements of order three.  But they generate the same subgroup.  Pair either of those with the element of order two in $C_2$.

For elements, we have a total of $6$, by my count.